# Confused by the .find() function

Tags: python, string

I'm currently taking the Codecademy python course. I wanted to iterate through the strings in a list and add any of the strings that show a dollar amount to the sales list, so naturally I wrote:

```
if transactions_clean[i].find('$') == True:
      sales.append(transactions_clean[i])
```

But this returned an empty list. Just as a random attempt to make something work, I changed it to

```
if transactions_clean[i].find('$') == False:
      sales.append(transactions_clean[i])
```

and suddenly the list contained every dollar amount in the original (transactions_clean) list. If I'm reading this right, its saying if you don't find the dollar sign in a string, add that string to the sales list... so why did it add every item that contained a dollar sign to the list?
If anyone wants to look at the exact problem it is the Codecademy Learn Python 3 Course under strings -> Thread Shed challenge problem. Thanks!

Comment: You need copy-paste your code and full error track, not everyone have Codecademy account.

Comment: `[i for i in transactions_clean if '$' in i]`

Comment: Why are you using `.find` like that? Like, what did Code Academy describe it as? It returns an int, not a bool. If you just want to check if a string *contains* a character, use `in` like @Onyambu said. See [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](/q/3437059/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

The `str.find()` function returns a non-negative position if found or `-1` if not found.

Hence you should not be comparing it with `True` or `False`<sup>(a)</sup>. Rather something like this would be better:

```py
if transactions_clean[i].find('$') != -1:
    sales.append(transactions_clean[i])
```

Although it would probably be considered more *Pythonic* to use:

```py
if '$' in transactions_clean[i]:
    sales.append(transactions_clean[i])
```

You could also just use one of:

```py
sales = [_ for _ in transactions_clean if '$' in _]
sales.extend([_ for _ in transactions_clean if '$' in _])
```

The first is if you know you're starting from an *empty* list, the second if you're appending to an *existing* list that may already contain elements.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In any case, it's considered bad form to compare against `True` or `False`. A better way is to convert things on the left so that they look like the right:

```py
Replace:            With:
-------------       --------
if x == True        if x
if x == False       if not x
```